Why is a docstring sufficient to satisfy a python's definition of a function when its body is empty?
I discovered this fun feature of Python, where this:
def do_nothing():
"""Does nothing."""
is the same as this:
def do_nothing():
...
I found someone commented this here:
" If you give your function a docstring, you don't even need to put any statement after the line with the docstring."
When is the usage of the Python Ellipsis to be preferred over 'pass'?
Could someone explain why the docstring acts as a no-op?
I have searched through the python language reference, and I see that python's function definition requires the body to have a statement.
I looked at the statement definition in CPython, and I don't see any references to an Ellipsis or docstring as a valid statement:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

A function does require a body. In your first example, the body is a string literal. That it's "a docstring" isn't a matter of formal syntax, but of context-dependent conventional interpretation. In your second example, the body is an Ellipsis object
>>> ...
Ellipsis
>>> type(_)
<class 'ellipsis'>

For exactly the same reason, these are also valid function definitions:
def f(): {}
def f(): 88
def f(): 3.14159
def f(): 1 < 2
def f(): pass

A statement of any kind is necessary and sufficient, even if executing the statement has no effect. The latter is a matter of semantics rather than of syntax. The syntax doesn't (and can't) enforce that the code will do something sensible.

Thanks, I found couple of good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735170/why-does-python-allow-an-empty-function-with-doc-string-body-without-a-pass
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76513104/empty-functions-methods-with-just-the-docstring-valid-in-python.
